# I updated my android sdk to include the Google Api's but adb connection is failing

Tags: android, sdk, adt

I updated my android `sdk` to include the Google Api's but `adb` connection is failing and am getting the following message

```
android `sdk` requires android developer toolkit version 23.0.0 or a bove current version is 22.0.0.v201305140200-- 675183.
```

I have tried checking for updates but failed

Comment: So you updated the android sdks? But did you update the build-tools too using the sdk manager?

Comment: Start up your SDK manager and get the 24.0.2 tools?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still using Eclipse? I guess you need to update Eclipse ADT as well...